# repeating regex to match mathematical symbol then number fails

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to match mathematica expressions like `1+2` and `1*2/3....` to infinity. Can someone explain why my regex matches the final case below, and how to fix it so that it matches only valid expressions (that might stretch forever)?

```
perms=["12+2*4","2+2","-2+","12+34-"]
perms.each do |line|
    puts "#{line}=#{eval(line)}" if line =~ /^\d+([+-\/*]\d+){1,}/
end
```

I expected the output to be:

```
12+2*4=20
2+2=4
```

Comment: If you want to match `"-2+3"` add `-?` at the beginning of the regex.

Comment: You want to match it "to infinity"? I hope you have a lot of memory and a fast machine.

Comment: Hyperbole, I assure you :) I just dont know how long the pattern will repeat for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside a `[character set]`, the `-` character defines a *range* of characters -- think of `[a-z]` or `[0-9]`. If you want to match a literal `-`, it must be the first or last character.

```
/^\d+(?:[+\/*-]\d+)+$/
```

Other things: `{1,}` is exactly `+`; and you need to anchor at the end too, so you don't match `1+2+`

Comment: What does the `?:` do? I thought the `?` was a non-greedy search, but that doesnt look like I expected.

Comment: `(?:expr)` -- `?:` makes the parentheses just for grouping: it does not capture the contents. It may save a few microseconds and a few bytes of memory if you don't need to store the parenthesized text for later processing.

Comment: See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/regexp_rdoc.html -- adjust the URL for your current ruby version.

Comment: In situations where either a capture or *non-capture* group would do, aside for the slight efficiency difference, by using the latter you are telling the reader that you have no need for the contents of the group.

Answer (score 0):

You should finalize your expression with `$` to match the entire input string:

```
/^\d+([-+\/*]\d+){1,}$/
```

The wrong position of the hyphen `-` is one source of error in your expression. The missing `$` the other.